# How to reference variables within a string on LiveCode?

Tags: livecode

I have a piece of code that I am trying to run, however I am trying to include variables as part of my string. This can be found in the line

put "A" into field "Field_(*position*)_(*lettersinword*)

The two asterisked words are the variables I would like to include. How do I do this?

```
global finalword
global lettersinword
global position
position = 0
on mouseUp
 repeat until position = lettersinword
  add 1 to position
  if char(position) of finalword = "a" then
   put "A" into field "Field_(*position*)_(*lettersinword*)
  end if
 end repeat
end mouseUp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string concatenation `&` in LiveCode but you also need to enclose the concatenation in parentheses:

```
...
put "A" into field ("Field_" & position & "_" & lettersinword) 
...
```